# Datalist items display when based on number of items

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am using DataList control in ASP.net application. I have set

```
DataList1.RepeatColumns = 3;
DataList1.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
```

properties of DataList. When item count is more than 3 it shows up properly. However if it is less than 3 it distorts and occupies whole space. 
e.g. if there is only 1 item, it takes complete width and distorts UI.
if $$$ is one item, for 3 it shows like,
$$$|$$$|$$$
for one item it shows like 
$$$$$$$$$$$

and UI disturbs completely.

Is there any way to format display in proper manner?

Answer (score 2):

As lcarus mentionned, try setting `ItemStyle-Width` property. Here is a snippet which worked for me:

```
<asp:DataList ID="myDataList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3"  HorizontalAlign="Center" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <ItemStyle  Width="33%" /> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <your code here>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

When requiring 3 columns, set the column width to 33%.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `ItemStyle-Width` property to the desired width. I would expect it to set the width of each item to the exact size you set it to: Here's a link to MSDN documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemstyle.aspx